# How to return a list of tuples as permuted form from a list of letters using merge sort?

Tags: python, recursion, permutation, mergesort

I have a list full of letters such as `li = ["m", "i"]` and I would like to return a list of tuples as permuted form **without using any libraries** as following,

```
[("m", "i"), ("i", "m")]
```

I try to use merge sort with recursion to solve this problem, however, which seems not returning the right output. My program is provided below,

```
def permutation1(lis):

    res = []

    if len(lis) == 1:
        res.append(lis)

    elif len(lis) > 1:

        last_index = len(lis) -1
        last = lis[last_index]
        rest = lis[:last_index]

        if rest is not None and last is not None:
            res.append(merge(permutation1(rest), last))

    return res


def merge(lis, c):

    res = []

    for s in lis:
        for i in range(len(s)+1):

            ps = s[:i]+ list(c) + s[i:]
            value =  tuple(list(ps))

            # print value
            res.append(value)

    return res
```

For example, with input of `["m", "i", "b"]`, I get output as `[[('b', ('i', 'm'), ('m', 'i')), (('i', 'm'), 'b', ('m', 'i')), (('i', 'm'), ('m', 'i'), 'b')]]` which is not correct.  How to improve the program so I runs as expected?

Comment: Does [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) help you anything?

Comment: @mwormser I don't want to use libraries. I try to learn properly how recursion and mer sort works together by solving this problem. It helps you for abstract thinking.

Comment: That would be a good thing to include in your question.

Comment: Okay, added in the original question.

Comment: I have tried debugging your code, but your style is such that it is torture. You have unclear variable names, with different variables having very similar names; no comments; and you do some unexplained strange things like placing a list inside a list (like `[['b']]`) with no clear reason. Refactor your code [according to PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and you will get more help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate all permutations of a list in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/104420/how-to-generate-all-permutations-of-a-list-in-python)

Comment: @Tonechas I would like to use merge sort to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
from itertools import permutations
[i for i in permutations(li,2)]
```

**Result**

```
[('m', 'i'), ('i', 'm')]
```

Here is without `permutations`

```
In [32]: [k for k in [(i,li[j])for i in li for j in range(2)] if len(set(k)) != 1]
Out[32]: [('m', 'i'), ('i', 'm')]
```

Comment: I don't want to use any libraries and mentioned in the original question.

Comment: @Arefe Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks, but, I would like to correct the code provided in the question.

Comment: For ``li = ['a', 'b', 'c']`` your code returns ``[('a', 'b'), ('b', 'a'), ('c', 'a'), ('c', 'b')]``. Is this the output expected by the OP?

Comment: No, that is not the expected output for the program. The tuples need to be composed of 3 elements.